# Proper ASP.NET MVC 5 Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Looking for some guidance as I am struggling here.

As someone who spent many years developing ASP.NET applications - that has been out of the game for 3-4 years, I am struggling to pick up the latest approaches. Probably as a result of a decade of experience.

My ASP.NET in the past was built using stored procedure calls, and the GUI was built using hand-coded HTML and JavaScript. I used JavaScript to emulate Ajax type functionality (before it was really a well known thing), and also would at times use XSLT to separate presentation from code.

Now, I am trying to move to MVC 5. It's not intuitive to me, and the few popular tutorials out there seem to be doing things that I don't want to do. For example, they are connecting to a simple table through EF, and allowing a user to view, edit or create items.

I'm looking for some basic things:

1. How do I get data from a stored procedure into some form of a view (GridView, or ListView, etc) - Using a controller, a View, a stored procedure as the data source (using Entity Framework? When i try DB First, and select to include procedures, I can't find them anywhere)
2. I'm going to want to allow them to *override* the value in one column. This would be stored down in the database as a different field.

This stuff was always very simple using basic web forms, but I can't find a tutorial that allows me to do anything other than just edit an existing table using EF - which isn't what I want to do. So tempted to just go back to the old fashioned way ...

This is one tutorial that was making sense to me, until it jumped into the code first approach on the database, where it went off the path from what I was looking to do:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Here was another one:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views
But this one was also different than what I was hoping to do.

I wish I wasn't so short on time with this project.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Well, this will likely be "too broad" for SO, but at the end of the day, it seems EF is where you find "too much" stuff. It "seems" that way, but in the end it does "simplify" (after the initial magical stuff :)). But, there's nothing stopping you from doing it "the ADO way" (still). You just have to manage things like you used to and "bind" them to UI using `Models` (without server controls) if you need to. A possible "middle ground" could be [Asp.net web pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages). Hth.

Comment: The ASP.NET Web Pages is interesting, looks like MVC Lite? I may try to stick with MVC as I appreciate the MVC aspect (I used to do that with XSLT back in the day), but maybe EF is just making it too complex right now. I can use help with how to iterate model properties in my views.

Comment: If you are comfortable with HTML and JavaScript, return data as JSON. Web API is the preferred way but MVC action methods can be used for that as well by returning `JsonResult`. There are many client side grids like `jqGrid`, `Kendo UI`, etc that are more efficient and just as powerful compared to web form controls like `GridView`.

Comment: WebForms is still a thing if you want to databind to grids etc. ASP.NET MVC is a cleaner approach and lends itself to better design. You have no viewstate and much more control over what is going on...
ORMs like EF are also becoming essential knowledge. I wouldn't advise ignoring them....
If your Model is a List<Something> you can construct your HTML table with its data in the View yourself. You can do a loop to create the rows...
If you are just too short on time, maybe picking up such huge changes is not great for right now. Use Webforms until you have time to really consume all the info.

Answer (score 0):

You may better wait for ASP.NET 5/vNext/MVC6 release and don't waste your time on MVC5. If your project relies on SQL and works well do not use Entity Framework at all.

Comment: I agree that EF does not make sense if your data layer uses stored procedures. Just call them directly. For read queries, there are lighter and more efficient micro ORMs like `NPoco`, that are almost as fast and flexible as raw ADO.NET but speed up development significantly.